# How do the Silent Assassin requirements work?

Tags: hitman-absolution

In Hitman: Absolution, certain actions earn you bonus points.  These bonuses add points to your score.  Based on your score at the end of the mission, you are given a ranking, on a scale from Agent to Silent Assassin.

What's confusing is that not only is "Silent Assassin" the best ranking, but one of the *bonuses* that you can achieve is also named "Silent Assassin".

I've also proved that it is possible to get the Silent Assassin Bonus, but lose the Silent Assassin Ranking through stupidity afterwards.

- **What are the requirements for the Silent Assassin Bonus?**
- **What are the requirements for the Silent Assassin Ranking?**
- **Is it possible to get the Silent Assassin Ranking without the Silent Assassin Bonus?**

Comment: Hope that helps, Steve.  If not, feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things that I have verified through testing so far.

#### To get the Silent Assassin Bonus:

- Agent 47 must have an assassination target.  Mission segments without a target cannot receive the Silent Assassin Bonus.
- Enemies **can** discover the corpses of your targets.
- Agent 47 **can** subdue non-target enemies.
- Collecting the evidence is **not** necessary.

#### To get the Silent Assassin Rating:

???

Answer (score 0):

Bonus

- Only kill the target
- Don't get spotted

Status

- Get high enough score

Comment: Bodies can be found.